# XPath expression to select *all* elements, text nodes, and comment nodes in source order

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

What’s the XPath expression to select *all* elements, text nodes, and comment nodes, in the same order as they appear in the document?

The following effectively selects all elements, but not text nodes and comment nodes:

```
var result = document.evaluate('//*', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null),
    index = -1;
while (++index < result.snapshotLength) {
  console.log(result.snapshotItem(index));
}
```

Is it possible to do something like the following? (Note: this is non-functional pseudo-code.)

```
document.evaluate('//* and text() and comment()');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//node()
```

selects every node that is a child of something: i.e  all elements, text nodes, comments, and processing instructions (but not attributes, namespace nodes, or the document node)

Comment: Woah! Short and sweet. This works great; it also selects the root element — and for HTML documents even the DOCTYPE (which I didn’t know was possible).

Comment: TIL that `document.evaluate('//node()', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue === document.doctype`.

Comment: If it selects a DOCTYPE node then someone has interpreted the XPath spec imaginatively; there's no such node in the XPath data model.

Comment: Thanks for the info; Opera indeed doesn’t match the DOCTYPE node. I’ve filed this as WebKit bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87888. Feel free to chime in there with more details!

Answer (score 1):

Tested with text and comment nodes in an XML document. There may be a more efficient approach, but this returns elements, text and comment nodes in document order for me, using union:

```
//*|//*/text()|//*/comment()
```

Comment: The question is about HTML (not necessarily XML) so you can just try it in the console on this Stack Overflow page, for example. That said, your answer appears to work fine. As an XPath n00b, I didn’t know about `|` — thanks!

Comment: Ah, in which case, welcome to `|` as `union`, and the immediate caveat that in XPATH 1.0 it only applies from the root of the query, you can't use it from midway through a "path".

Comment: Oh, and a good way of bootstrapping your XPATH knowledge is to check out some of the answers by the top users for the tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/topusers