# Why are comments ignored in DOMDocument even when selecting "*" elements?

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm trying to loop through *all* elements in the HTML string. A comment block is still an element, at least to me. But it's ignored:

```
$HTML_string = '<div><p><!-- a comment --></p></div>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document_data = new DOMDocument;
$document_data->loadHTML($HTML_string);
$nodes = $document_data->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach ($nodes as $node)
    echo '"' . $node->nodeName . '"' . PHP_EOL;
```

**Actual output:**

```
"html"
"body"
"div"
"p"
```

**Expected output:**

```
"html"
"body"
"div"
"p"
"<!--" or "comment"
```

I've seen a SE question which specifically deletes comments by referring to them explicitly with `DOMXPath` and `query('//comment()')`, but I need it to be done in my existing, general "element iterator" as shown above.

Why aren't the comments treated as existing?

I've searched very long and hard now without finding any information on this. Like so many other things, it's just an unexplained mystery, and I'm the only one in the world wondering about it.

Comment: [You can use `//node()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816891/965834)  if using XPath is fine.

Comment: You are selecting elements by tag name. A comment does not have a tag name.

Comment: From the docs: The special value * matches all tags. A comment, obviously not being a tag, will not be included.